# Is it correct to write $\lim_{x \to a} \ f(x) = \nexists$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

On a function that has no limit in $a$, is it correct to write

$$
\lim_{x \to a} \ f(x) = \nexists
$$

Is that equal sign correctly put?

Thank you.

Comment: No, that's a hideous misuse of notation.

Comment: That equal sign is completely incorrect. You are basically saying that the limit is equal to a negation of a quantifier, which is utter nonsense.

Comment: No, don't do this. $\exists$ and $\not\exists$ are prefixes. You can say $\not\exists L:\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L$.

Comment: $\not\exists$ is not a synonym of "does not exist." And it is meaningless to say "$X=\text{does not exist}$" anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not. The usage of that symbol is not of that form.

Write

> The limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: thank you. If I remove the equal sign, does that make it right?

Comment: @bru1987 No. A quantifier always goes *before* a symbol which is then mentioned. If you insist on using it, you could write $\not\exists l: l=\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$, but even this is borderline acceptable, and most of all, completely unnnecesary, since saying "the limit does not exist" is not hard at all.

Comment: It is not accetable.

Comment: There is no need to use notation when perfectly good words exist and are not in the least inconvenient.

Comment: The problem with $«\not\exists l:l=\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$» is that when the limit does not exist, the notation $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ simply cannot be used, as it does not denote anything.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez That's why I said "borderline". It's still ugly, but not as bad as the original solution.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{x \to a} \ f(x) = \nexists
$$
Write that only for your own personal notes, or if your textbook writes it that way.  Other people (such as those answering here) will tell you it is **incorrect**.

I have also seen this recommended:
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \ f(x) \;\;\;\text{D.N.E.}
$$
for "does not exist".  But use the same cautions with this one.

How to do it then?

Why not use English?
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \ f(x) \;\;\;\text{does not exist}
$$
or even better
$$
f(x) \;\;\text{does not converge as }\;\; x \to a
$$

Comment: Better still, do not write it *even* in your personal notes.

Answer (score 1):

A quantifier needs a variable. Write

$$\nexists r\in\mathbb R\lim_{x \to a} \ f(x) = r.$$

Not entirely kosher because one really should not write expressions that don't exist, but at least the (negated, existential) quantifier has a variable $r.$

Comment: Yep, sorry, non-native speaker and I wrongly assumed that all languages had the same Latin :-)